# Using jenkins to build mulitple versions of an IOS app with a single target

Tags: ios, xcode, build, jenkins

I have an ios app that will have two versions (using preprocessor directives to determine what code to use for which version). I would like to automatically build each version of the app using Jenkins. I would also like to use a single target in the xcode project if possible. Is the possible using a multiple-configuration project in Jenkins; and if so, I would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the XCode scheme in your build script.

For example, if you had two schemes on for testing, say staging and production, you would need to have to build scripts that look similar to this.

```
xcodebuild -configuration Debug -scheme "Test Staging" -sdk iphonesimulator5.1 -arch i386 build
xcodebuild -configuration Debug -scheme "Test Prod" -sdk iphonesimulator5.1 -arch i386 build
```

Your schemes can then be configured in XCode to match the preprocessor directives.

Comment: thanks, that works as intended. Also got it working using: GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS="ENGLISH=0" to set the preprocessor directive with xcodebuild